# Cross-policy domain file for Flash

Tags: flash, cross-domain

I have an Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET web application with a Flash file inside of it.

The flash connects a Red5 media server on the same machine.

I'm trying to run it, but it gives me a `Error #2032`, which [this page](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Flex_Error__2032__Stream_Error-17265.html) says I need a cross-policy domain file.

I'm only trying to go from `localhost:8386`  to `localhost:5080/[webapp]`

Which Schema should I use?

What do I name the file?

What do I put in the file?

### Update

I put this: `crossdomain.xml` inside `red5/webapps/vod`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

And it worked, kind of.

Only I get a NetConnection.Connection.Closed error, so we're making progress.

### Update 2

Either Visual Studio 2010 or Flash is giving me some frustrating problems.

In order to troubleshoot which directory the file actually goes in, I had removed the .xml file from each directory just to see which directory the file actually NEEDED to be in.

I ended up removing **all** of the `crosspolicy.xml` files, and my flash still connected, which made me think that the data was just stored in a cache somewhere.

- I deleted my Flash local storage, but it still connected.
- I ran CC cleaner on the basic settings, but it still connected.
- I rebooted my computer, but it still connected.
- I cleaned and rebuilt the VS2010 webapp, but it still connected.

I'd really like to narrow down what directory this file needs to be in, but because things are stored in some hidden cache somewhere, I can't pin down what I need to do, since this webapp is impervious to any changes I make, apparently.

I'll ask another question on how to clear my cache.
Stupid VS2010...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save this as `crossdomain.xml` in root of your web server running on port 80 if any. Else put it in `red5/webapps/root/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="localhost" to-ports="5080"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: I got a similar domain file to work when I put it in `webapps/vod`. I'll update